# swift compilation error: Downcast from 'String?!' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!!'?

Tags: swift, types, casting

After upgrading to cocoapods 1.0, I get this compilation error for these lines of code:

```
var strName = String()
var strEmail = String()
var strFacebookID = String()
var strPassword = String()
var objHelper = Helper()

....

let strFirstName = result["first_name"] as! String
let strLastName = result["last_name"] as! String
self.strName = strFirstName + "_" + strLastName
self.strEmail = result["email"] as! String
self.strFacebookID = result["id"] as! String
```

> Downcast from 'String?!' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!!'?

Here is a screenshot of the error in detail:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Ssz.jpg

UPDATE:
more code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c91c2eb1ccf269e78a118970468d1e8

Comment: What's the type of result?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ According to the error message `result` is `AnyObject?`.

Comment: @Axil is using it as a dictionary, did you mean [String : AnyObject] ?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Right, but anyway `result` is an optional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message says that `result` itself is an optional so you have to unwrap both `result` and the value respectively.

```
let strFirstName = result!["first_name"] as! String
```

or better using optional binding for more safety and less type casting

```
if let userData = result as? [String:String] {
   let strFirstName = userData["first_name"]!
   let strLastName = userData["last_name"]!
}
```

Comment: this i think solves it. got other errors come out. I have no idea what you are doing as Im trying to fix someone else swift code. What is the exclamation mark for ! and what is as? Thanks for helping on my ignorance.

Comment: The exclamation mark unwraps an optional and causes a runtime error (crash) if the optional is `nil`. The question mark in conjunction with `if-let` unwraps the optional and casts the value to the specific type on success otherwise skips the `if` clause.  Please read the basics in the Swift Language Guide.

Answer (score 1):

`result["key"]` itself returns an optional, because there is a possibility that the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

You'd need to first unwrap that optional, and then cast the returned value to a String. Try this:

```
let strFirstName = result["first_name"]! as! String
```

This is kind of a code smell, it's a lot of casting. Perhaps that dictionary should be of type `[String : String]` rather than what it is now.

Answer (score 0):

For me just removing the `as! String` worked.
So instead of,

```
let strFirstName = result!["first_name"] as! String
```

replace with,

```
let strFirstName = result!["first_name"]
```